# Asio resolver does not take io_service object as an argument

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I've run into a bit of a problem when using the `asio` standalone library. I'm sure that my issue is something silly that I have forgotten/overlooked, but I can't for life of me figure out what it is. Perhaps you can help me.

According to asio documentation I should be able to create a resolver object by doing `asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);` where `io` is a previously defined `asio::io_service` object. I am doing this inside of a class and to do this I understand that you must use class initializer lists. However, this is where I run into a problem. I have copy and pasted my code below, and I believe I do this properly, but perhaps you can tell me otherwise.

```
#pragma once
#include <asio.hpp>

class asiostuff
{
private:

    asio::io_service io;

    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver;

    asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query;

    asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
public:
    asiostuff()
       : resolver(io)
    { //<---- red squiggly line says no default constructor exists

    }
};
```

Now, I *think* I am doing it right, but MSVC outputs a C2512 error when I attempt to build this (no appropriate default constructor available). When I do

```
    asio::io_service io;

    asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);
```

outside of the class, it compiles just fine, which indicates to me that I am probably doing the class initializer list wrong. Is there any object I should initialize before initializing the `asio::ip::tcp::resolver` object?

For reference, I am using MSVC 2015 compiling for x64 in Release mode.

**EDIT:** After some additional testing, I've found that when I comment out `asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query;` and `asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;` the program compiles again. Why?

Comment: It looks like query may not have a default constructor.

Comment: Ah. It doesn't, I didn't realize that would cause this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Mikel F solved this in his comment.

Query did not have a default constructor and needed to be properly constructed.

MSVC wasn't smart enough to tell me that specifically and I wasn't experienced enough to know.